# In an augmented matrix representing a system of equations, why is it a contradiction when the LHS isn't zero and RHS is zero but not when flipped?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

In an augmented matrix representing a system of equations, say a $1\times 3$ matrix: $(a,b \mid c)$, why is it a contradiction when $a=b=0, c\neq 0$ but not when $a,b\neq 0, c=0$ ?

Comment: If you meant to say an augmented matrix (i.e. representation of an equation $ax+by=c,$ then the contradiction is apparent when $a=b=0$ and $c\neq 0.$  Fox example if $c=1,$ then $0x+0y=1,$ implying $0=1.$   On the other hand if $a=-1,$ $a=1$ anc $c=0,$ we have an equation $-x+y=0.$  Why is this not a contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are talking about [augmented matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix) for systems of linear equations. Such a system is described by a matrix equation $Ax=c$, where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, $b$ a column vector of $m$ rows and $x$ (column vector of $n$ rows) are the solutions you are looking for. You write this system just as $(A\mid c)$. Now when $A=0$ and $c\neq 0$, we are dealing with $0x=c$, which can't have any solutions, since $0x$ (where $0$ is the $m\times n$ zero matrix) is always $0$ (the column vector of $m$ zeros), so can't be equal to $c$ being non-zero.

On the other hand, when $A\neq 0$ but $c=0$ you can indeed have solutions. For example
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} \pmatrix{0\\1} = \pmatrix{0\\0}.
$$

Comment: I should've looked up the definition... Thanks.